How to include sync Project as part of a AWX workflow?
The first template (ansible playbook) adds files to the GIT repo, which is a Project in AWX.
The second step needs to sync the Project so that the next template can use those files.
Update Revision on Launch doesn't work because it launches before the template that uploads the files to the repo.
For example:
git_add_files runs but if Update Revision on Launch is on the Project is sync'd then git_add_files runs.
What is needed is:
git_add_files then playbook/template to sync the Project then template/playbook that uses the uploaded files.
I was hoping that Update Revision on Launch would work.
I have cache set to 3600.
If I set it really low then the sync would run with every template.
